# Lit Element, unit testing - Nested Elements - Child element does not render

Tags: unit-testing, web-component, web-testing, lit-element, react-testing

I am very new to lit-element and unit testing and am not sure if the question is even framed correctly. Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

So, I have 1 lit component created such that it fetches the json from the uri
`<abc infoJsonLink="../data/data.json"></abc>`

data.json

```
[
 {"id":1, "name":"one", "img":"one.jpg"},
{"id":1, "name":"two", "img":"two.jpg"}, 
...]
```

Within abc's render() method, we loop through the json data and create a array with html markup corresponding to each item, `itemsMarkupList`

```
 *0* <div "item-data"><span>one</span><img src="one.jpg"/></div> 
 *1* <div "item-data"><span>two</span><img src="two.jpg"/></div>  
 *2* ...
```

Each one of these markups, has to be rendered in a bootstrap carousel. https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/ascensus/135508

For this we have created another component, `<carousel-helper>`, which has the code to accept an array of markups and render it as a carousel using bootstrap libraries.

Below is the `render()` method of `<abc>` component

```
render(){... 
let ch = document.createElement("carousel-helper"); 
ch.itemsMarkupList = this.itemsMarkupList;
return html`... <div class="parent_wrapper"> ${ch} </div>`;
}
```

This whole renders perfectly when I `npm run` it.

But when I am writing the test cases for this,  the shadowroot of child elements seems to be not rendering.

```
  it("test1", async () => {
   const el = /** @type {Abc} */ (await fixture(
    html`<abc infoJsonLink="/data/data.json"></abc>
    `));

  await el.loadJsonData();

  /*statement 1*/
  console.log(el.shadowRoot.querySelector("carousel-helper")); 

  /*statement 2*/
  console.log(el.shadowRoot.querySelector("carousel-helper").
    shadowRoot.querySelectorAll(".item-data"));

  });
```

*statement-1* works and returns `<carousel-helper></carousel-helper>` 
*statement-2* return and empty array, `NodeList {}`

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get a filled array from *statement-2*?

Comment: And with a setTimeout delay around statement 2?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I tried setTimeout... it doesn't change anything... and if i try putting the expect() within settimeout() , it doesnt show any output...

Comment: Without a working (or in your case failing) code-snippet, there is nothing to try. It basically comes down to verifying DOM exists, top-down. You can't get ``.item-data``; but can you access its shadowRoot

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman You are right! I can access the shadow root. But the DOM does not exist within child, so i dont get `item-data` . So what are the options I have to check `expect` only when the shadow DOM of child element is completely loaded.
I also tried `await el.updateCompleted()`. But no difference.

Comment: So your next debugging step is: What/when does ``item-data`` get created. Whack plenty of ``console.log`` statements in to fully grasp the what/when. Adding ``setTimeout`` is a trick to delay execution. SInce you didn't get a result with a setTimout wrapper function, something else is (not) happening (or you did setTimeout wrong)... but it is impossible to tell without running code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Since the web component `<abc>` is dynamically loaded, you need to ensure it is *defined* before performing tests. Don't use timeouts or intervals, try the following before you query the element:

```js
   await customElements.whenDefined('abc');
```

Here's some more info on [customElements.whenDefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined).